# Using Mark.js in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, mark.js

I'm using the wrapper  [ngx-markjs](https://github.com/kievsash/ngx-markjs) to use Mark.js inside my Angular 11 app.

It works as expected on static text:

```
<span [markjsHighlight]="textToSearch">
    some static text, including some words that will be highlighted by mark.js</span>
</span>
```

But if I add a variable, it does not highlight anything anymore (even on the static text part not concatenated to the content via the variable):

```
<span [markjsHighlight]="textToSearch">
    some static text and a dynamic variable {{question.text}} => mark.js won't work anymore
</span>
```

Highlighting only static text is, well, not so useful ; How should I proceed to include and highlight variable text content?

Answer (score 0):

Classic! I found the solution just after asking, while getting up to grab a glass of water *!* Hopefully, it will benefit someone else.

Using `innerHTML` worked:

```
<span [markjsHighlight]="textToSearch" [innerHTML]="question.text"></span>
```